# knockout checkbox with dropdown events

Tags: knockout.js

Current functionality is selected items will be displayed when click on select check-box and vice versa is working fine.

I want also show the dropdown selected value along checkbox and vice-versa.

```js
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.choices = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray([]);
viewModel.testing = ko.observableArray();

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    viewModel.testing(viewModel.selectedChoices());
    //return viewModel.selectedChoices().join(",");
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Select Items</h1>
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: choices">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </label>
        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="1">Two</option>
            <option value="1">Three</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<h1>Your Selected Items</h1>
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: testing">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        </label>
        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="1">Two</option>
            <option value="1">Three</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well the trick here is you should carry the `dependency` throughout without breaking it .

**view:**

```
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: Looper">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="attr: { value: $data.name }, checked: $parent.selectedChoices" /><span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>

        </label>
        <select data-bind="options:$root.listDD,optionsText:'val',optionsValue:'id',value:selectedOne"></select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**viewModel:**

```
function Builder(item) {
    this.name = ko.observable(item)
    this.selectedOne = ko.observable();
}

function Generator(choices) {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(choices, function (item) {
        return new Builder(item);
    })
}
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.choices = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
viewModel.listDD = ko.observableArray([{'id': 1,'val': 'one'},{'id':2,'val': 'two'}, { 'id': 3,'val': 'three'}]);

viewModel.Looper = ko.observableArray(Generator(viewModel.choices));
viewModel.testing = ko.observableArray();
viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray();

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.computed(function () {
    if (viewModel.selectedChoices()) {
        viewModel.testing([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.selectedChoices(), function (item1) { 
            ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.Looper(), function (item2) {
                if (item1 == item2.name()) {
                    viewModel.testing.push(item2);//Here we are now passing exact dependency rather creating instance(if created dependency destroyed)
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Working sample up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25564/)** to check

Answer (score 2):

Your viewmodel should model the view more closely. Each object you use has a label, a checkbox, and a selector. It also makes sense to model the options list in the view model rather than in the HTML.

`dependentObservable` has been superseded by `computed`.

Here's how I reworked it:

```js
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.options = [
  {name: 'One', value: 1},
  {name: 'Two', value: 2},
  {name: 'Three', value: 3}
];

function choice(label) {
  return {
    label: label,
    chosen: ko.observable(),
    selectedValue: ko.observable()
  };
}

viewModel.choices = [
  choice("one"),
  choice("two"),
  choice("three"),
  choice("four"),
  choice("five")
];
viewModel.testing = ko.computed(function () {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.choices, function(item) {
    return item.chosen();
  });
});
viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.computed(function () {
  var labels = ko.utils.arrayMap(viewModel.testing(), function (item) {
    return item.label
  });
  return labels.join(',');
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Select Items</h1>
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: choices">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: chosen" /><span data-bind="text: label"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="" id="" data-bind="options: $parent.options, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', value:selectedValue">
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<h1>Your Selected Items</h1>
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: testing">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: chosen" /><span data-bind="text: label"></span>
    </label>
    <select name="" id="" data-bind="options: $parent.options, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', value:selectedValue">
    </select>
    <div data-bind="text:selectedValue"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited "></div>
```

Comment: I am able to get the selected checkbox value but how to get the dropdown selected value against checkbox checked.

Comment: @PawanBali `selectedValue` is the dropdown selected value. I put it in a `text` binding in the Your Selected Items section.